# Convert iframe to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help. I want to convert this iframe into this textarea, so I can be able to write text in it. I try the below code, but it's not working.

Here are my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#richTextField").on("load", function () {
            var str = $(this).contains().find('html').prop('outerHTML')
        });
    });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prof.css">
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="script/Working.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="iFrameOn();">

            <div id ="addtext" class="panel">
                <form action="my_parse_file.php" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">

                    <!--                <div id="rte" contenteditable="true" unselectable="off">Write here ....</div>-->
                    <div id="menu">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iBold()" value="B"> 
                    <input type="button" onClick="iUnderline()" value="U">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iItalic()" value="I">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iFontSize()" value="Text Size">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iForeColor()" value="Text Color">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iHorizontalRule()" value="HR">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iUnorderedList()" value="UL">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iOrderedList()" value="OL">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iLink()" value="Link">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iUnLink()" value="UnLink">
                    <input type="button" onClick="iImage()" value="Image">
                    <textarea style="display:none;" name="rte" id="rte" cols="100" rows="14"></textarea>
                    <iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe>
                    <br /><input name="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit Data" onClick="javascript:submit_form();"/>
                    </iframe>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was hoping that some can help me.

Comment: Well, for one, there's a rogue `</iframe>` closing tag in there, before the two closing `</div>`s

Comment: Thank for pointing that out to me